# Trouble with transitive and intransitive verbs

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this appropriate place to post . I am self learning Japanese after a long time of not touching the language. I am now trying to understand the concepts of when to use transitive  vs intransitive verbs and I am struggling alot. After reading my book and some lessons online I can understand the rules for making one verb from intransitive to transitive, but im confused as to how to approach learning verbs in general.

When write my own sentences for practisce now, should I be thinking "is this verb transitive", "is this verb intransitive"? This concept is really confusing me. When I read japanese I can usually understand the meanings of the sentence but im not really thinking about whether the verb is transitive or not.

Comment: Your question is in the meta SE, not the main SE (Click on the striped speech bubble in the top right and pick "Japanese Language"). You probably would have more luck getting an answer over there. Though I think questions about transitive/intransitive have been asked many times, so it might be a good idea to search around there first, whether there already is an answer that would help you, before posting.